# Does AppEngine Flex support runtime .NET 5

Tags: google-app-engine

Not finding documentation with the list of runtime supported currently, other than [customizing runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/customizing-the-dotnet-runtime)

I get this error:

```
Step #0: gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/aspnetcorebuild@sha256:f5552a5efdaf278a3124ea10fd1c9636b09fc9f98f9e620cbd71279797576b3f
Step #0: The app requires .NET Core runtime version 5 which is not supported at this time.
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this post (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-visualstudio/issues/847), it's the same case as yours were they report working fine 'til version 2.0.X (Last comment is from last year).

In the documentation, even though is not specified that is the last supported version, it makes a code example with core version 2.1: [The .NET Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/runtime).

In that same document is provides a another link with a [list of images provided by google to build .NET containers] (http://gcr.io/google-appengine/aspnetcore) were the higher version used is 3.1.

Unfortunately, it seems to be no list (as is) of supported version in the documentation.